# How to solve $\int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi }|f(x) |^2 dx $?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let  the $f(x) \in L^2 [-\pi, \pi]$

(Here the set$ L^2 [-\pi, \pi] =\{f(x)| \int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi }|f(x) |^2 dx <\infty\}$)

Say  $\int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi }f(x)e^{-inx}dx =0$ for all $n$ $\in$ integer, $Z$

Then what is $\int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi }|f(x) |^2 dx $?

---

Intuitively the answer might be 0

But I couldn't get any idea for solving that.

Thanks

Comment: The answer will almost never be $0$ since you're integrating a nonnegative function.

Comment: To your shock and dismay the answer is $0$!. @Allawonder

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You're telling me that $$2\int_0^π{f(x)^2\rm d x}$$ vanishes for any nonzero function continuous on that interval? Why not take $f(x)=x,$ for example.

Comment: You are forgetting the hypothesis which forces $f$ to be the zero function if $f$ is continuous.  (In general it is $0$ almost everywhere). @Allawonder

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see no such hypothesis in OP. I've looked again; if you're talking about where he said *Say...,* then I'd taken that as a particular example he'd been working with. I took the claim after the line as being applicable to the integral in the title.

Comment: This is a question from the theory of Fourier series. You won't understand what I am saying if you never heard of Fourier series and Fourier coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\{e^{inx}:n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is an orthnormal basis for $L^{2}[-\pi, \pi]$ and $2\pi \int_{-\pi} ^{\pi} |f(x)|^{2} dx=\sum_n |\int_{-\pi} ^{\pi} e^{-inx} f(x)dx|^{2}$ for any function $f \in L^{2}[-\pi, \pi]$. Hence the answer is $0$.

Comment: This cannot be proved by more elementary methods.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $s_n(t):= \sum_{k=-n}^nc_k e^{-ikt}$ the n-th partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$.

Since $\int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi }f(x)e^{-ikx}dx =0$ we have that $c_k=0$ for all $k$.

On the other hand:

$||f-s_n||_2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$

Since $s_n=0$ for all $n$, the result follows.